# PL/SQL Needs exception handling

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to put a where others clause in this procedure in the blank space before the end and it needs to insert error logs into an additional table I need to know how to go about doing this.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TRANSFER_many_DOCS
AS
 p_cac_id  CTRT_DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT_ID%TYPE;
  p_last_name  CTRT_DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT_NAME%TYPE;
  p_domain_description  CTRT_DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT_EXTENSION%TYPE;
  p_rev_number CTRT_DOCUMENT.COURSE_DOCUMENT%TYPE;
  p_item_titile  CTRT_DOCUMENT.CREATED_BY%TYPE;
  p_document_name  CTRT_DOCUMENT.CREATED_DATE%TYPE;
 
 CURSOR SEL_RW_VE IS
 SELECT  P_CAC_ID, P_LAST_NAME, P_DOMAIN_DESCRIPTION,P_REV_NUMBER, P_ITEM_TITTLE, P_DOCUMENT_NAME FROM LMS_EXTRACT;
 BEGIN /* 1 */
OPEN SEL_RW_VE;

LOOP 
FETCH SEL_RW_VE INTO P_CAC_ID, P_LAST_NAME, P_DOMAIN_DESCRIPTION, P_REV_NUMBER, P_ITEM_TITTLE, P_DOCUMENT_NAME;
IF SEL_RW_VE%NOTFOUND
THEN
COMMIT;
EXIT;
END IF;

BEGIN /* 2 */
INSERT INTO CTRT_TEST.CTRT_DOCUMENT (DOCUMENT_ID, DOCUMENT_NAME, DOCUMENT_EXTENSION, COURSE_DOCUMENT, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE);

*where clause exception handling goes here*

  BEGIN /* 3 */ 
INSERT INTO CTRT_TEST.CTRT_DOCUMENT (DOCUMENT_ID, DOCUMENT_NAME, DOCUMENT_EXTENSION, COURSE_DOCUMENT, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE)
VALUES P_CAC_ID, P_LAST_NAME, P_DOMAIN_DESCRIPTION,P_REV_NUMBER, P_ITEM_TITTLE, P_DOCUMENT_NAME FROM CTRT_TEST.LMS_EXTRACT;
  END;  /* 3 */
END;  /* 2 */
END LOOP;

CLOSE SEL_RW_VE;
END;
```

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in [DML error logging](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-B71385AD-2D21-42F3-9249-3D6364887746)?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line which says `*where clause exception handling goes here*` - that's the wrong place to put the EXCEPTION block.

Just before the line which reads `END; /* 2 */` add the following:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE(SOME_FIELD) VALUES ('SOME VALUE');
```

Change the INSERT statement to insert whatever values are needed into your table.